# Intel Rapid Storage Technology - Raid5 is very slow

Tags: raid, storage, raid5

I build a computer with a raid5, using the motherboards raid controller (ASUS P7H57D-V EVO - intel Rapid Storage Technology). The read and write are however very slow, when using the raid controller :( - I am using Windows 2008 R2, and when using the windows software raid, it was ok in speed - so there must be an issue with the controller? Im using 6 disks on 2TB each.

Do anyone have any idea why its so slow, and how to fix it? I rather not pick the easy solutiuon of "just buy a raid controller" :|

If you need more info about my setup, please just ask.

Thanks :)

Comment: Not a solution, but you really shouldn't be using RAID-5 with multi-terabyte drives. You're quite likely to have a failure during rebuild, see http://www.zdnet.com/blog/storage/why-raid-5-stops-working-in-2009/162. With drives as cheap as they are, using RAID-10 is far safer (and performs much better for writes).

Comment: @rmalayter, note that most newer drives are a couple orders of magnitude less likely to have an error; which is not accounted for in the linked article. URE of 10^16 is pretty common, and 10^17 is being seen in common SATA drives. I've seen enterprise SAS drives quoted as high as 10^21.

Comment: Very bad question. What is "very slow"? (rhetoric question)

Comment: @Chirs S, the Seagate barracuda XT and Western Digital Caviar Black are still rated at URE=10^14. These are the mainstream multi-terabyte "volume" SATA drives from each vendor. RAID5=bad on such drives (assuming the UREs from the manufacturer can be trusted). Of course "enterprise near-line" drives might be better (even if they use the same mechanisms, they might have more ECC in the firmware layer).

Comment: This is why its recommended on linux to get MDADM to run a badblock check every few weeks. echo check >> /sys/block/mdX/md/sync_action

Comment: Provide clearer explanation on what has changed, what has not, and more precise speed measurements ("very slow" is quite subjective).

Answer (score 1):

Did you just build the array? its possible that it is still syncing all the drives. on a 5x1TB array it took me 9 hours and during that time it was very very slow as there was a lot of background processing and writes.

Comment: Given no information from the OP on the state of the array syncing going on ins a likely culprit. It takes ages of time to sync a large raid and during this time - obviously - a lot of the IO budget is tied up for the sync process.

Answer (score 0):

Check driver versions. It should not be high performance compared to a controller, but it should be comparable to windows own RAND implementation.

Comment: I did install the latest version of the driver - no change :(